# AES Encryption between .NET WinRT and iOS Obj-C isn't the same

Tags: c#, objective-c, encryption, windows-runtime, aes

I'm having a hard time getting my iOS AES encryption/decryption the same as the one I have on WinRT.

I can't change the implementation on the WinRT side since it's used in a published app.

Here are two sampls I made with zeroed key and zeroed iv, the outputs are differents.

C# sample code :

```
using (MemoryStream saveDataMemoryStreamCrypto = new MemoryStream())
{
    var saveDataKeyProvider = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
    var saveDataKeyBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(new byte[32]);
    var saveDataKey = saveDataKeyProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(saveDataKeyBuffer);
    var saveDataSaltBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(new byte[32]);
    var saveDataDataBuffer =  Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary("ABCDEFGH", Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16BE);
    var saveDataOutBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(saveDataKey, saveDataDataBuffer, saveDataSaltBuffer);
    var saveDataOutBytes = saveDataOutBuffer.ToArray();
}
```

C# bytes output :

80 87 109 195 133 40 205 81 117 91 17 132 229 3 119 251 205 8 246 64 13 57 210 142 11 153 121 39 122 196 63 10

Obj-C sample code :

```
Byte keyPtr[32];
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
Byte ivPtr[32];
bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));

NSString *text = @"ABCDEFGH";
NSUInteger dataLength;
void * buffer = malloc([text length]);
[text getBytes:buffer maxLength:[text length] usedLength:&dataLength encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, dataLength) remainingRange:nil];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength * kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void * bufferOut = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256, ivPtr, buffer, dataLength, bufferOut, bufferSize, &numBytesEncrypted);
```

Obj-C bytes output :

23 144 186 234 149 182 123 79 155 234 250 54 52 38 151 87 179 62 176 1 203 115 59 1 35 54 176 1 44 213 120 1

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: First get your sizes correct. You need a 16 byte IV, and your objective C buffer cannot hold the UTF16 encoding of your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code, the main difference is the data length accounts for UTF16 being two bytes per character:

```
u_int8_t  keyPtr[32];
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
u_int8_t  ivPtr[32];
bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));

NSString *text = @"ABCDEFGH";
NSUInteger dataLength = [text length] * 2; // Allow for utf16
void * buffer = malloc(dataLength);
[text getBytes:buffer maxLength:dataLength usedLength:nil encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, dataLength) remainingRange:nil];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength * kCCBlockSizeAES128;
u_int8_t * bufferOut = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256, ivPtr, buffer, dataLength, bufferOut, bufferSize, &numBytesEncrypted);

printf("encoded text in decimal: ");
for (int i=0; i<numBytesEncrypted; i++) {
    printf("%d ", bufferOut[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Printf output:

> encoded text in decimal: 80 87 109 195 133 40 205 81 117 91 17 132 229
>   3 119 251 205 8 246 64 13 57 210 142 11 153 121 39 122 196 63 10

Yes, it is really awful code, I made the minimum changes necessary. I guess a new era is being entered with data dumps in decimal, hex is dead.